How to do a GDPR-friendly Age Verification? Save data after cookie consent?
I'm going to need an age verification for a website. The problem is GDPR.
If the user clicks "yes, I'm over 18" I have to ask for cookie consent before storing it anywhere.
Is there any way to do this without saving the data as a cookie, sessionStorage or localStorage? Or can I in some way save the data AFTER the cookies have been consented to?
I will be using CookieBot for the GDPR compliance if that helps.
